# Pegar html de serviço e exibir DIV em meu site

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tenho uma função Ajax que me retorna o html de um serviço que tenho exposto, gostaria de pegar esse html e colocar dentro da DIV de um site meu.

Minha função já está pegando html, porém ele exibi o html dentro da DIV gostaria que exibisse o conteúdo já formato, sem as tag de html

Comment: por jQuery: `$("#suaDiv").html("<html> seu html </html>")`

Comment: Perfeito! Deu certo amigo! Agora preciso pegar os campos do meu formulário e passar na url para o serviço, tentei assim:
 $.get('.endereco.com.br/Simulacao2',$('form_t').serialize(),function(responseText) { 

Mas ele não pega meu form. Sabe o pq?

Comment: Vê se assim te atende:`$("#suaDiv").html = $.parseHTML("<html> seu html </html>")` ou `$("#suaDiv").html($.parseHTML("<html> seu html </html>"))`

Comment: @William edita sua pergunta com o código que você tenta fazer o `.get`

Comment: Tentei assim: "$.get('endereco.com.br/Simulacao2',$('form_t').serialize(),function(responseText) { "

O nome do meu form está como fom_t

Comment: vc tá mandando como se fosse `post`, tenta assim: `$.get('endereco.com.br/Simulacao2' + $('form_t').serialize(),function(responseTex‌​t) { }`

Comment: @ Marllon Nasser Não deu certo, meu form está assim: <form id="form_t" name="form_t" class="col s12" method="post">

Ele não passa os campos para a url, engraçado que na versão antiga do meu formulário funcionava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformando o comentário em resposta...

Basta utilizar jQuery:

```
$("#suaDiv").html("<html> seu html </html>")
```

Para enviar seu form via get:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data:  $("#form_t").serialize(),
    url: "endereco.com.br/Simulacao2"
}).done(function(data){
    //tratamento
});
```